# Difficulty with tmap tools package - can't load distGeo

Tags: r, tmap

I'm having trouble loading the package 'tmap'. When I try R returns the message Error : object ‘distGeo’ is not exported by 'namespace:geosphere'
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tmap’
I can load the geosphere package which this seems to relate to but tmap won't load. Does anybody have any ideas? I am new to tmap, and am trying the tutorial 'Introduction to visualising spatial data in R' at https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/intro-spatial-rl.pdf
I believe the version of tmap I'm using is the latest one.
Cheers,
Dan

Comment: Strange, distGeo is exported. Could you run a `sessionInfo()`. Does it help to do `library(tmaptools)` first?

Comment: Cheers. If I try to load the tmaptools package first it returns the exact same error message about distGeo that I get when I try to load the tmaps package. sessionInfo() returns: > sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_New Zealand.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_New Zealand.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_New Zealand.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                         LC_TIME=English_New Zealand.1252

Comment: continued : attached base packages:
character(0)

other attached packages:
[1] tmaptools_1.2
attached base packages:
character(0)

other attached packages:
[1] tmaptools_1.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.9        magrittr_1.5       grDevices_3.3.2    geosphere_1.3-13   xtable_1.8-2       lattice_0.20-34   
 [7] R6_2.2.0           tools_3.3.2        utils_3.3.2        dichromat_2.0-0    grid_3.3.2         KernSmooth_2.23-15

Comment: [13] e1071_1.6-8        htmltools_0.3.5    stats_3.3.2        crosstalk_1.0.0    datasets_3.3.2     class_7.3-14      
[19] leaflet_1.1.0      digest_0.6.12      base_3.3.2         shiny_1.0.0        RColorBrewer_1.1-2 htmlwidgets_0.8   
[25] graphics_3.3.2     mime_0.5           sp_1.2-4           methods_3.3.2      classInt_0.1-23    XML_3.98-1.5      
[31] httpuv_1.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Ah, `distGeo` only exists as of version 1.4-3 of `geosphere`. So this problem should be solved when you update geosphere.

I will specify this version dependency in the DESCRIPTION file of tmaptools.

Thanks for letting me know, Dan!